# Trying to scrape data from website, have to navigate multiple tags

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to navigate the HTML of a webpage and scrape data.  I think i have identified the correct tags, but when i assign the values to a list and chack the length, i get nothing.  I have been using the following code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://seatgeek.com/justin-bieber-with-kehlani-and-jaden-smith-tickets/philadelphia-pennsylvania-lincoln-financial-field-2020-08-01-7-pm/concert/5164898'

response = requests.get(my_url).text
soup = soup(response, 'lxml')

containers = soup.find_all('div'),{'data-e2e':'event-listing'})


print(containers)
```

When i run this, i get

> output: []

i have also tried

```
containers = soup.find_all('div'),{'class':'omnibox__listing ds-0 omnibox__listing--alternate-layout'})
```

This gives me the same result, nothing.

Comment: Did you check if the data is in the HTML returned by the request? Also, you import BeautifulSoup as `soup`, but also name a variable `soup`, which is a bad idea.

Comment: just changed my variable "soup" to "sauce".  Thank you

Comment: im pretty sure its in the code - i can find it very easily when i hit inspect on the web page.   currently on JS beautifier trying to confirm that it is but im not sure why it wouldnt be?

Comment: the element which you are trying to find is not in HTML content of the soup.

Comment: _im pretty sure its in the code - i can find it very easily when i hit inspect on the web page._ The real question is whether Requests and BeautifulSoup can get you those elements, though.

Comment: why would they not be able to get the elements? im under the impression it gets all of it.. im new but going through the readthedocs for beautiful soup and requests

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to fiddle around with HTML then you can send a GET request to the address below.  If you open your browser and check the network requests that the web page sends to get its' data, it returns all the results in a JSON.

https://seatgeek.com/rescraper/v2/listings?_include_seats=1&client_id=MTY2MnwxMzgzMzIwMTU4&id=5164898&sixpack_client_id=5270c621-c506-48f4-8420-0a06161f718b